# Warning: Encountered two children with the same key. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have encounter this error in my website console, however, I have no idea where the bug came from, is there anyway to chase where is the bug code?

It likely because I have use some nested object in my react component when may contain same sub-key, like: `x["cat"][1]`, `x["dog"][1]`, is there any wrong of defining object like this? Or it's not the problem?

```
app-index.js:31 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `0`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
    at tbody
    at _c4 (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./components/ui/table.tsx:55:11)
    at table
    at div
    at _c (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./components/ui/table.tsx:20:11)
    at div
    at div
    at Model (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./app/model/page.tsx:98:11)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:227:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:59:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:324:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:102:11)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:139:9)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:213:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:15:44)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:334:11)
    at InnerLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:227:11)
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:59:11)
    at LoadingBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:324:11)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:102:11)
    at InnerScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:139:9)
    at ScrollAndFocusHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:213:11)
    at RenderFromTemplateContext (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js:15:44)
    at OuterLayoutRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js:334:11)
    at div
    at body
    at html
    at RedirectErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:73:9)
    at RedirectBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/redirect-boundary.js:81:11)
    at ReactDevOverlay (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:70:9)
    at NotFoundErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:51:9)
    at NotFoundBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found-boundary.js:59:11)
    at HotReload (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/hot-reloader-client.js:318:11)
    at Router (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:94:11)
    at ErrorBoundaryHandler (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:77:9)
    at ErrorBoundary (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:102:11)
    at AppRouter (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:375:13)
    at ServerRoot (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:162:11)
    at RSCComponent
    at Root (webpack-internal:///(app-client)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:178:11)
```

Comment: It's a problem of the DOM, not how you store data. If you have two or more elements with the same "key" attribute, the warning appears. Look for your `.map()` clauses where you put "key" attribute in your child elements.

Comment: I had multiple `.map()` clauses in my jsx, how can I know which one is the problem? @technophyle

Comment: From your error, it's happening in a `tbody`, so maybe look for your `tr` iterations and `console.log` the values that are put in `key` attributes.

Comment: Glad I could help. I posted it as an answer, so please accept it if it helped you so others could also get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two or more elements with the same `key` attribute, the warning appears. Look for your `.map()` clauses where you put `key` attribute in your child elements.

From your error, it's happening in a `tbody`, so maybe look for your `tr` iterations and `console.log` the values that are put in `key` attributes. And if you find a duplicate, get rid of it.